# PHP refresh site after post

Tags: php, forms

I make some changes on my db with php. The result i want to see after sending the formular. The side refreshes but the changes are not there. If i put f5 everything ist fine. Is there a solution to fix it?

```
<form action="" method="Post">

    ........

if(isset($_POST["saveMetrics"]))
{
    $_DB = new DBData();
    $_DB -> connect();
    $str = "";
    for ($i = 3; $i < count($_metricsFb); $i++)
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$_metricsFb[$i]['COLUMN_NAME']]))
            $str=$str.$_metricsFb[$i]['COLUMN_NAME']."=1";
        else
            $str=$str.$_metricsFb[$i]['COLUMN_NAME']."=0";
        if($i!=count($_metricsFb)-1)
        {
            $str=$str.",";
        }
    }
    $queryCALL ="UPDATE t_user_metrics SET ".$str." WHERE id_user=";

    $_DB -> setMetrics( $_GET["client"],$queryCALL) ;
    header("Location: dailyReport.php?client=".$_GET["client"]." success=true");
    $_DB ->disconnect();          
}
    <div><input type="submit" class="button" name="saveMetrics" value="Save"></div>                     
</form>
```

it doesnt works if i five the path to action.

```
header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

doesnt works too!
I thougt it could be possible to open another window which refresh his parent. But ther must be an easier way. Anyone an idea?

Comment: f5 or ctrl+f5? if ctrl, then the cache is messing you up and you should probably add `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to submit your form to the same script displaying the page?  If yes, you can do something like this `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Comment: f5 is enough but then i send the formular again (isnt bad but not cool thats why i put enter on the url)

Comment: @SciGuyMcQ what i want is probably very simple. i do some changes by sending the formular. the changes i want to see without refreshing the site again (the refresh of sending the formular could be enough)

Comment: sry no is only a short cut from my code. i edit it thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, You are displaying data before execution of update script. Try to move your code before it.

```
if(isset($_POST["saveMetrics"]))
{
    $_DB = new DBData();
    $_DB -> connect();
    $str = "";
    for ($i = 3; $i < count($_metricsFb); $i++)
    {
        if(isset($_POST[$_metricsFb[$i]['COLUMN_NAME']]))
            $str=$str.$_metricsFb[$i]['COLUMN_NAME']."=1";
        else
            $str=$str.$_metricsFb[$i]['COLUMN_NAME']."=0";
        if($i!=count($_metricsFb)-1)
        {
            $str=$str.",";
        }
    }
    $queryCALL ="UPDATE t_user_metrics SET ".$str." WHERE id_user=";

    $_DB -> setMetrics( $_GET["client"],$queryCALL) ;
    header("Location: dailyReport.php?client=".$_GET["client"]." success=true");
    $_DB ->disconnect();          
}

... your <form> and other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url with `header`.

```
header("Location: yoururl.php?success=true");
```

Maybe try it like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['success'] && $_GET['success']=="true") {
   echo "Your data has changed.";
}
```

Comment: yes i tried at the end of the formular. it doesnt works. u know another spot?

Comment: @nicoschuck I've added a piece of code to my original comment.

Comment: i see the problem ist he dont change the header. i added some code maybe u understand the problem. if i send the formular the getparameter succes isnt to find in the url